# Android app force close with error cat provided

Tags: android, forceclose

**Hi, first-timer here. totally new.**
I have same problem for my newly developing app followed by youtube tutorial. Everything looks fine but it just force close, I have used the log cat and saw java.lang.NullPointerExceptions , FATAL Execption: main , android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage etc.

Really no idea how and what can I do to resolve it. perhaps I should just post the whole error log just to show my problem?

http://wallpapertry.blogspot.sg/2012/10/blog-post.html

Comment: post relevant snippet of code. ALso welcome to stackoverflow. Read the faq

Comment: Did you declare your activity in android manifest?

Comment: Some thing is null, means you haven't instantiated it